# bootstrap nav-bar with vertical buttons and a form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, button

I am comfortable with HTML and I am learning Bootstrap (ver3). I have a page with a NAV-BAR on the top. Below that, I have a multi-select drop down list with  a ‘Submit Button 2’. Originally, I had a set of FORM tags around the Multi-select box. When Submit Button 2 was clicked, it did as expected and displayed the POST values.

In the standard NAV-BAR examples, they have the FORM tags around the NAV-BAR buttons. When I had this configuration, when Submit Button 1 was clicked, the multi-select values were not collected by POST. This is obvious because the multi-select box was not between the NAV-BAR FORM tags. They have their own set of FORM tags.

So for my example below, I have only one set of FORM tags, and they are at the top and the bottom of my BODY tags. Now, both submit buttons collect the POST values.

However, they have one bad side effect. With a view port larger than my phone, the three buttons on the NAV-BAR are stacked vertically. I need them to be horizontally. I have seen possible fixes with span tags, but I can’t see how this works for what I need.

With my final page, I will have 3 sets of radio buttons and two multi-select drop down boxes. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Dan

```js
$('#example-post').multiselect({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  enableFiltering: true
});

$('#example-post').search1({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  enableFiltering: true
});
$('#example-post').search2({
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  enableFiltering: true
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Multiselect search-test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post">
    <center>
      <br><br><br> <br><br><br>
      <!-- needed to bring down the multi-select below the menu bar --->
      <?php
                      echo '--------------------------- search test ----------------------------<br>';
                      print_r($_POST);
                      echo '<br>---------------------------------------------------------------------<br>';
         ?>

        <div>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-right" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    
                            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Our Search Engine</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" name="search2">Submit Button 1</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" name="Something">Something</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" name="Quit">Quit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <h3>Select<br></h3>
              <select id="example-post" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" required>
                            <option value="Jenny">Jenny</option>
                            <option value="Mary" selected>Mary</option>
                            <option value="Cathy">Cathy</option>
                         </select>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="search2">Submit Button 2</button>
            </div>
            <!-- row -->
          </div>
          <!-- container---->
        </div>
    </center>
    </div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `form-control` from button  `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" name="search2">Submit Button 1</button>`